# Replace adsense with admob in webview app

Tags: google-adsense, android

I've made a webview app for my wordpress website.

I'm using Adsense. I recently found out that one can't use Adsense in mobile apps.
I want to replace my Adsense units with Admob.

Somebody told me there's a javascript based solution for this issue, it would display adsense/admob based on the whether the webpage is being accessed in an app or in a browser.

I'm not sure if this solution violates Google Adsense TOS or not.

What other options do I have? Is my only option is to develop a native app for my website?